# Display Images from Google Drive on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

**The ask:**
I need to reference and display several images from a shared drive onto a google sheet. The shared drive contains images only available to people who have access to that drive. These are not publicly available. These images will be updated daily by other people who have access to this drive. I would like the sheet to reference the drive and automatically update the images when someone replaces the file with the same file name.

**The problem:**
If I embed the image from drive onto google sheets, it does not reference / update when the image is replaced in the drive.

**the workaround:**
I CAN insert the hyperlink of the image from Drive. (Insert > Function > Web > Hyperlink) and this works to reference the image in drive and it also works if someone replaces that image with a different one with the same file name. However this doesn't solve my display image issue. Is there a way to display those images? Any other ideas?

Comment: About `I CAN insert the hyperlink of the image from Drive. (Insert > Function > Web > Hyperlink) and this works to reference the image in drive and it also works`, I think that in this case, the image file is required to be publicly shared. But you say `These are not publicly available.`. So, I cannot understand your current situation. Also, I cannot understand `However this doesn't solve my display image issue. Is there a way to display those images?`. Can I ask you about the details of them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.